# Span button is not reacting to a click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, click, parsley.js

I'm doing a complicated multistep form using ParsleyJS for a service request and I encountered a weird issue today.
I've got some `span` elements that are treated as prev/next buttons. But some `spans` works and some of them not.

I've uploaded the multistep form to my server. You can check it [here](http://rr171.stronazen.pl/zsform/). For the demo purpose, in the first form input please type **`IN1615`** and go next two times.

In step 3 (Krok 3) the next button is not working. It isn't even reacting to the jQuery click event. `$('.next').click(function(){ console.log('it should work! why it is not?'); });`

Anyone know why this happens? Any help or advice is very useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: where is code? give jsfiddle

Comment: How can I paste 10 files into jsfiddle? You can check the source live on the site. Link is in the question.

Comment: Comeon its in another language,and in website , everything is working properly wats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

$(document).on()try adding some apostrophes to .next

```
$('.next').click(function(){ console.log('it should work! why it is not?'); });
```

also, didn't look too deep but if anything is being built dynamically, you might be better off using

```
$(document).on('click','.next', function() { 
    //console.log('it should work! why it is not?');
    console.log('It does. It does work. Use it.'); 
});
```

EDIT: I inspected your page. Step 3 is **not** part of the DOM when the page finishes loading. I pasted the "IN1615" into the input like you said, and then step 3 through step 14 *are* in fact **dynamically** created. This is the reason your `$('.next').click()` listener doesn't work.
Again, I recommend you use `$(document).on()` like in the code snippet above, as it will listen to events triggered on DOM elements that are built *after* the page loads. 
If you are ever using dynamically created html, `$(document).on()` is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('.next').click(function(){ console.log('it should work! why it is not?'); });
```

if static Dom elements. Else use `on` event.

You have single quotes missing here `'.next'`.

Comment: I tried with single quotes but wrote here in question and didn't pay attention to the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is going to work, but in script.js, try replacing:

```
$('.next, .prev').on( 'click', function () {
```

with

```
$('#main-form').on( 'click', '.next,.prev', function () {
```

It appears, for some reason, that the $('.next, .prev').on.... is only attaching to the first two spans, the spans that were originally displayed.